# OOP Based config file

Tags: php, oop, url-routing, spl-autoload-register

I have a config file for my app but I am having trouble passing the object around as I need it to be available to my main index page and parent controller.

Currently I have to pass it as a parameter for the __Construct function in every controller I make, which certainly doesn't seem to be the best way to do it.

index.php

```
<?PHP

require 'config/conf.php';
$errors = array();

//Memcache the config file at some point.

define('DEBUG_MODE', 0);

define('SITE_KEY', '');

define('ROOT', 'http://manager.com/');


define('Vs', 'views/');
define('Cs', 'controllers/');

function __autoload($className) { // Autoload both controllers and models.
    if (stristr($className, 'Model')) {
        if (is_readable(Ms . $className . '.php')) {
            include Ms . $className . '.php';
        }
    } else {
        if (is_readable(Cs . $className . '.php')) {
            include Cs . $className . '.php';
        }
    }
}

require 'libs/core/Controller.php';
require 'libs/core/View.php';

$Memcache = null;
if ($config['ADDITIONAL_LIBS']['MEMCACHED']) {
    if (!class_exists('Memcache')) {
        $errors[] = array('code' => 1, 'type' => 'error', 'title' => 'Memcached failed to load', 'msg' => 'Memcached is not installed or initialised properly.');
    }
}

if ($config['SESSIONS']) {
    require 'libs/core/Session.php';
}

if ($config['DATABASE']) {
    define('Ms', 'models/');
    require 'libs/core/Database.php';
    require 'libs/core/Model.php';
}

if ($config['ADDITIONAL_LIBS']['UTIL']) {
    if (file_exists('libs/extra/Util.php')) {
        require 'libs/extra/Util.php';
    } else {
        $errors[] = loadFail('Util');
    }
}
if ($config['ADDITIONAL_LIBS']['PBKDF2']) {
    if (file_exists('libs/extra/PBKDF2.php')) {
        require 'libs/extra/PBKDF2.php';
    } else {
        $errors[] = loadFail('PBKDF2');
    }
}
if ($config['ADDITIONAL_LIBS']['MCAPI']) {
    if (file_exists('libs/extra/MCAPI.php')) {
        require 'libs/extra/MCAPI.php';
    } else {
        $errors[] = loadFail('MCAPI');
    }
}

require 'libs/core/Router.php';

$Site = new Router($Config, $errors);

function loadFail($moduleName) {
    return array('code' => 1, 'type' => 'error', 'title' => $moduleName . ' failed to load', 'msg' => $moduleName . '.php was not found in the "libs/extra/" directory.');
}
```

My conf file:

```
$Config = new Config();

$Config->set('HOME_PAGE', 'index');
$Config->set('MEMCACHE_ENABLE', true);
$Config->set('MEMCACHE_SERVERS', array(
    array(
        'SERVER' => 'localhost',
        'PORT' => '11211'
    )
));

class Config {

    public $params;

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function set($param, $value) {
        $this->params[$param] = $value;
    }

    public function get($param) {
        return $this->params[$param];
    }

}
```

And my main controller class which I need the config object to be accesible from:

```
abstract class Controller {

public $view;
public $Memcache;

public function __construct($Config) {
    // Autoload model if it exists...
    $model = get_class($this) . 'Model';
    if (is_readable(Ms . $model . '.php')) {
        if ($Memcache) {
            if (!$this->model = $Memcache->get($model)) {
                $this->model = new $model;
            }
        }

    }
    $this->view = new View();
}

}
```

What is a slick and clean way to achieve what I want, which is basically to have a centralised configuration file who's parameters are available to both my main index file and parent controller?

Comment: You should look into Singleton Pattern for yuor config. Usually a good idea.

Comment: Have you considered making your config an abstract class rather than dealing with concrete instances of the class?

Comment: @edvinas.me Considering this question is tagged OOP having a global magic object is certainly not a "good idea".

Comment: How is it not a good idea for configuration? I always believed it would be one of the rare cases when the use would be apropriate.

Comment: Because you just don't need a global (including all its problems) for this.

Answer (score -2):

Config is typically handled using the Registry pattern:
http://avedo.net/101/the-registry-pattern-and-php/

That's probably the most common/straightfoward way to do it. Some people prefer not to make config quite so global, in which case you would often use the Factory pattern and let the factory inject the config so that you don't have to explicitly do it with each instantiation.